# Media field content is not showing in API output

Tags: strapi

I'm facing this issue where the Media field doesn't show up in the output even though it's populated. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could check out this post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249364/components-not-included-in-strapi-api-response/70251184#70251184) I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Populate the image field in your request -> http://localhost:1337/api/something?populate=somthing.image

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).