# Strapi v4: can't add an image to entry with API

Tags: strapi

I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong. The upload works. The image gets added to the media library. But it's not added to the entry.

Here’s my screenshot (Postman request):

[image]

Comment: Try adding populate to your url, maybe that will solve your problem. Example here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249364/components-not-included-in-strapi-api-response/70251184#70251184)

Comment: @IceJonas thanks for response but I'm trying to create not get so that there is no queries for api endpoint of creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I can tell from the docs is that you might need to change `ref` field value to `api::article.article`

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#upload-files-related-to-an-entry

I hope this helps! I had the same issue and this resolved my issue. Strapi docs aren't the easiest to get around :(