# Media field is not showing up in api response of strapi v4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, strapi

I have a media field in my collection of strapi (v4) server named **Picture** but it doesn't come up in api response when I request localhost:1337/api/products.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Components not included in Strapi api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249364/components-not-included-in-strapi-api-response)

Answer (score 31):

Solved, yay!

Documentation of Strapi v4 says:

> **Relations population**
>
> By default, relations are not populated when
> fetching entries.
>
> Queries can accept a populate parameter to explicitly define which
> fields to populate, with the following syntax:
>
> `GET /api/books?populate=*`

So I had to just postfix my GET request with `?populate=*`

Answer: `localhost:1337/api/products?populate=*`

Comment: for me doesnt work, I get this :  error: Invalid URI "/api/homes?populate=%2A"

Comment: try this
localhost:1337/api/homes?populate=*

Do add the response you get if this doesn't work.

Comment: this only works only the images are in same collection. what if the images in collection type and after we adding relation ? this is not working for that

Answer (score 3):

After reading Strapi Docs - [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#component-dynamic-zones), turn out you can populate directly the media fields -

```js
const qs = require('qs');
const query = qs.stringify({
  populate: [
    'seoData',
    'seoData.sharedImage',
    'seoData.sharedImage.media',
  ],
}, {
  encodeValuesOnly: true,
});

await request(`/api/articles?${query}`);
```

instead of populating all(by *) which is not a good practice because,

1. Data classification - In most cases, you don't need to return the entire payload such as when the collection is published and so forth.
2. Performance - When you select only the necessary ones, your query to the DB will be more minor and therefore the result will come faster.
3. Reduce payload - When you select only the necessary ones, you reduce the payload that returns to the client.

Answer (score -2):

at last write, populate=picture(name of media field)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't work for me