# Get response from strapi api for image in a component

Tags: components, vuejs3, strapi, headless-cms

I'm trying to get my url img in my axios response from fetching my posts content-type from strapi api.
Here what I've done: I create my posts content-type and I create a components which contains fews media's slot:

[image]

Then I call the end point http://localhost:1337/api/posts?populate=*
but I can't get any data from this components:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Components not included in Strapi api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249364/components-not-included-in-strapi-api-response)

Comment: same isue, i find my solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249364/components-not-included-in-strapi-api-response

Answer (score 4):

You will have to deeper into it.
Call your endpoint like this:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/posts?populate[ImgWidget][populate]=*
```

Comment: Working as expected. :)

Answer (score -1):

try this one, i try it and it works for me:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/posts?populate=Posts.image
```

if you have images or image_video you can use this link:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/posts?populate=Posts.image&populate=Posts.images&populate=Posts.image_video
```

please tell me if that works for you!