# How can I write a strapi query to get my posts and image from a category content type

Tags: strapi

I created a collection type 'posts' and created many posts. Now I made another collection-type of category with ['softwaresApps','gifts','technology'] title that holds relations of posts. then i tried fetching with `http://localhost:1337/api/categories?populate=*"` and get:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Technology",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:43:05.899Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-09T00:45:26.131Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-01-09T00:44:04.298Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Gifts",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:43:48.196Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-09T00:43:53.979Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-01-09T00:43:53.961Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "softwares&apps",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:48:23.706Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-11T00:06:48.130Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-01-09T00:49:59.571Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "attributes": {
            "title": "HomeSlider",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-15T15:06:23.122Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-15T15:06:30.272Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-01-15T15:06:30.259Z"
        }
    }
],
"meta": {
    "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 25,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "total": 4
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find my posts relations in the data. I need a query that can help me fetch all the posts & images from the cateories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Components not included in Strapi api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249364/components-not-included-in-strapi-api-response)

Answer (score 7):

I have figured it out. thanks to @IceJonas, his link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251184/17908449

It turns out populating with `http://localhost:1337/api/categories?populate=*"` is not going to cut it. I found the solution whereby you have to populate deeper using - `http://localhost:1337/api/categories?populate[posts][populate]=*` and you will populate all the relations including their images.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "softwareapps": "softwareapps",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-18T01:42:01.223Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-18T01:43:37.935Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-01-18T01:43:37.931Z",
            "posts": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "attributes": {
                            "title": "The Best Drones for Photos and Video",
                            "date": "2022-01-11",
                            "article": "The **most** of your time with a _laptop_ is spent in a browser, you can get a better experience for your money with a [Chromebook.](wirecutter.com) \n\nNena Farrell has covered technology and connected home products since 2016, originally at Sunset Magazine (where she was an associate home editor) and now as an updates writer on the audio, visual, and smart-home team at Wirecutter.\n\nBrendan Nystedt contributed to an earlier version of this guide. He’s been an enthusiast photographer and a writer covering consumer electronics and tech for the better part of a decade. Nystedt has worked for Wirecutter, Reviewed, and Wired, and he has written for numerous other outlets.\n\nWhile preparing this guide, we consulted reviews both from owners and from trustworthy outlets, such as Wired and PCMag. Unfortunately for the layperson shopping for these devices, there are many SEO-driven clickbait blogs offering hands-off reviews. We ignored those websites.\n\n",
                            "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:07:30.402Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-01-16T23:27:06.589Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2022-01-09T00:07:33.230Z",
                            "author": "chisom ifem",
                            "subCategory": "phone",
                            "postId": "3",
                            "readTime": "4",
                            "category": "softwareapps",
                            "popular": true,
                            "homeStartHere": false,
                            "slug": "The-Best-Drones-for-Photos-and-Video",
                            "image": {
                                "data": {
                                    "id": 17,
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "name": "pg5.jpg",
                                        "alternativeText": "pg5.jpg",
                                        "caption": "pg5.jpg",
                                        "width": 1470,
                                        "height": 735,
                                        "formats": {
                                            "thumbnail": {
                                                "name": "thumbnail_pg5.jpg",
                                                "hash": "thumbnail_pg5_cbcb14de57",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 245,
                                                "height": 123,
                                                "size": 12.24,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_pg5_cbcb14de57.jpg"
                                            },
                                            "large": {
                                                "name": "large_pg5.jpg",
                                                "hash": "large_pg5_cbcb14de57",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 1000,
                                                "height": 500,
                                                "size": 63.18,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/large_pg5_cbcb14de57.jpg"
                                            },
                                            "medium": {
                                                "name": "medium_pg5.jpg",
                                                "hash": "medium_pg5_cbcb14de57",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 750,
                                                "height": 375,
                                                "size": 39.5,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/medium_pg5_cbcb14de57.jpg"
                                            },
                                            "small": {
                                                "name": "small_pg5.jpg",
                                                "hash": "small_pg5_cbcb14de57",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 500,
                                                "height": 250,
                                                "size": 23.05,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/small_pg5_cbcb14de57.jpg"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "hash": "pg5_cbcb14de57",
                                        "ext": ".jpg",
                                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                        "size": 93.38,
                                        "url": "/uploads/pg5_cbcb14de57.jpg",
                                        "previewUrl": null,
                                        "provider": "local",
                                        "provider_metadata": null,
                                        "createdAt": "2022-01-12T23:37:47.189Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2022-01-12T23:37:47.189Z"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "attributes": {
                            "title": "The Best Mop-Vacuum Combo Is the Bissell CrossWave",
                            "date": "2022-01-10",
                            "article": "The Aeezo Portrait 01 is considerably cheaper than our other picks (it’s nearly half the price of the Aura Mason), and it’s surprisingly good. The frame is minimalist but doesn’t look cheap, and the Aeezo has a unique feature that allows you to easily re-crop a photo so that no matter the orientation, it always looks good. The downside is the uploader, which limits you to 10 pictures at a time and is overall frustrating for the less-tech-savvy to navigate and understand.\n\n# This is the end hommies",
                            "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:00:30.997Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-01-17T00:19:05.116Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2022-01-11T22:24:52.541Z",
                            "author": "Emeka olumma",
                            "subCategory": "phone",
                            "postId": "2",
                            "readTime": "3",
                            "category": "gifts",
                            "popular": true,
                            "homeStartHere": false,
                            "slug": "The Best-Mop-Vacuum-Combo-is-the-Bissell-CrossWave",
                            "image": {
                                "data": {
                                    "id": 21,
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "name": "slide2.jpg",
                                        "alternativeText": "slide2.jpg",
                                        "caption": "slide2.jpg",
                                        "width": 1470,
                                        "height": 735,
                                        "formats": {
                                            "thumbnail": {
                                                "name": "thumbnail_slide2.jpg",
                                                "hash": "thumbnail_slide2_de6b7dcd32",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 245,
                                                "height": 123,
                                                "size": 11.51,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_slide2_de6b7dcd32.jpg"
                                            },
                                            "large": {
                                                "name": "large_slide2.jpg",
                                                "hash": "large_slide2_de6b7dcd32",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 1000,
                                                "height": 500,
                                                "size": 43.34,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/large_slide2_de6b7dcd32.jpg"
                                            },
                                            "medium": {
                                                "name": "medium_slide2.jpg",
                                                "hash": "medium_slide2_de6b7dcd32",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 750,
                                                "height": 375,
                                                "size": 30.53,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/medium_slide2_de6b7dcd32.jpg"
                                            },
                                            "small": {
                                                "name": "small_slide2.jpg",
                                                "hash": "small_slide2_de6b7dcd32",
                                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                                "width": 500,
                                                "height": 250,
                                                "size": 19.62,
                                                "path": null,
                                                "url": "/uploads/small_slide2_de6b7dcd32.jpg"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "hash": "slide2_de6b7dcd32",
                                        "ext": ".jpg",
                                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                        "size": 52.52,
                                        "url": "/uploads/slide2_de6b7dcd32.jpg",
                                        "previewUrl": null,
                                        "provider": "local",
                                        "provider_metadata": null,
                                        "createdAt": "2022-01-15T15:33:30.925Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2022-01-15T15:33:30.925Z"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "attributes": {
                            "title": "Laptop you can buy now in 2022",
                            "date": "2022-01-14",
                            "article": "A digital photo frame lets you easily add images—including beautiful travel shots and family photos—to the frame from anywhere. Whether you’re giving a frame as a gift and plan to upload photos remotely, or you just want a great frame for yourself, the Aura Mason is the best frame we’ve used. Its 8.57-inch display is sharp, bright, and vivid, and in our tests it was the simplest to set up. On top of that, it has a good-looking design.\n\nOf all the frames we tried, the Aura Mason came the closest to mimicking a regular photo frame. The Mason is straightforward to set up and use, and remotely loading photos is a breeze (the free Aura app works with Android and iOS phones). With this frame it is easy to add photos on the app or through a web uploader. From the intuitive design of the app to the frame’s pared-down interface, the Mason is not just for the tech-savvy.\n\n\n### The Aura Mason\nThe Aura Mason Luxe is an upgrade to the Mason, with a larger price tag. That extra cost adds a slightly larger 2K screen and video capabilities onto everything we already like about the Mason frame. But even though the video capabilities are nice, we don’t think they’re truly necessary in order to enjoy a digital picture frame.\n\n\n\nThe [Aeezo Portrait](wirecutter.com) 01 is considerably cheaper than our other picks (it’s nearly half the price of the Aura Mason), and it’s surprisingly good. The frame is minimalist but doesn’t look cheap, and the Aeezo has a unique feature that allows you to easily re-crop a photo so that no matter the orientation, it always looks good. The downside is the uploader, which limits you to 10 pictures at a time and is overall frustrating for the less-tech-savvy to navigate and understand.\n\n",
                            "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:18:35.467Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-01-16T23:05:11.379Z",
                            "publishedAt": "2022-01-09T00:18:38.306Z",
                            "author": "John juzzy",
                            "subCategory": "phone",
                            "postId": "6",
                            "readTime": "3",
                            "category": "softwareapps",
                            "popular": false,
                            "homeStartHere": false,
                            "slug": "Laptop-you-can-buy-now-in-2022",
                            "image": {
                                "data": {
                                    "id": 13,
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "name": "kids3.png",
                                        "alternativeText": "kids3.png",
                                        "caption": "kids3.png",
                                        "width": 206,
                                        "height": 142,
                                        "formats": null,
                                        "hash": "kids3_eee4bde396",
                                        "ext": ".png",
                                        "mime": "image/png",
                                        "size": 54.89,
                                        "url": "/uploads/kids3_eee4bde396.png",
                                        "previewUrl": null,
                                        "provider": "local",
                                        "provider_metadata": null,
                                        "createdAt": "2022-01-09T00:16:21.166Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2022-01-09T00:16:21.166Z"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"meta": {
    "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 25,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hi any idea on how to paginate the populated array?